# Can't install Codebook package in R

Tags: r, installation, rstudio

I am attempting to install the R package "codebook" on OSX. I receive the following error message. I receive similar error messages when I try to independently install these dependencies. Is there a way that I install via the terminal or otherwise install these dependencies?

My apologies if this is not enough information in order to provide guidance. Please let me know and I would be happy to provide additional context. I am using RStudio Version 1.0.136

Thank you

```
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
 installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘lavaan’, ‘OpenMx’, ‘semTools’ are not available for package ‘MBESS’
  installation of package ‘MBESS’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘igraph’ is not available for package ‘DiagrammeR’
  installation of package ‘DiagrammeR’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘RcppEigen’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘DiagrammeR’ is not available for package ‘data.tree’
  installation of package ‘data.tree’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘car’, ‘data.tree’, ‘DiagrammeR’, ‘lavaan’, ‘lme4’, ‘MBESS’ are not 
 available for package ‘userfriendlyscience’
 * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/userfriendlyscience’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘userfriendlyscience’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘userfriendlyscience’ is not available for package ‘codebook’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/codebook’
```

Comment: Not having `car` available (among all of them) seems odd, as that's a common package. Some thoughts: RStudio 1.0.136 was released in [Dec 2016](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200716783-RStudio-Release-History). R-3.4.0 was released in [April 2017](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.4.0/), about the same. Both are rather out-dated, I would frankly be a little surprised if all packages were easily available today. If at all possible, I would start by recommending an upgrade to at least RStudio 1.2 and R-3.5 (if not 3.6).

Comment: CRAN only keeps binaries for the current minor version (3.6) and previous (3.5), which means if you're on 3.4 at this point, you're going to have to build everything from source. In this case, something is going wrong with compiling RcppEigen before the part you copied here. It may be that you don't have the xcode command line tools installed (run `xcode-select --install` in a terminal) or something else entirely. But update first.

Comment: ...and [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is super-nice for installing these things and keeping them up-to-date. You can install current R and RStudio with `brew cask install r rstudio`.

Comment: these were all really fantastic suggestions. thank you